# Process Backbone collection fetched data before firing event

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I have Backbone collection and collection view with listener:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
```

Then at some point I do this:

```
myCollection.fetch({
    reset: true,
    success: myCallback
})
```

What I want is to do some changes to the models (maybe even delete or replace some of them) depending on what's happening on the page. And I want to do it *before* rendering the view. Currently I'm trying to do it in `myCallback`, but see that it called after rendering.

How can I process fetched data before any events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `parse` method of collection to modify the fetched response before the events trigger like:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
 parse: function(response){
   // modify response here
   return response;
 }
});
```

Or for some reason if you want to run your code on actual modal instances after models are created then you can just manually call render instead of the event listener like:

```
myCollection.fetch({
  reset: true,
  success: function(collection, response){
   // modify response here
   view.render();
  }
})
```

Or have a different callback that manipulates the modal and then calls render like:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.preRender);
  },
  preRender: function(){
    // manipulate models here
    this.render();
  },
  render:  function(){
   // Actual rendering here
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the second solution is what I need. But isn't  it better to trigger some event for rendering instead of storing link to view inside collection?

Comment: @DenisK. *"storing link to view inside collection"* - no, my second example assumes you're doing `myCollection.fetch({` inside the view, or a router, where you have a reference to itself. Don't make any links to view in model/collections. If your collection constructor has access to collection instances like `myCollection` then there is something wrong with the design... Anyway if you want to stick with events I've added an alternative.